# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros tipo STRING dentro de una función JS en echo PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de pasar los parámetros tipo string con espacios en blanco, dentro de una función JS dentro de un echo, ejm:

```
$variable = "Hola mundo";

echo '<a onclick="funcionJS('.$variable.');"</a>';
```

La verdad, en éste sentido no estoy muy familiarizado con la teoría, sé que el error viene de las comillas (' '), pero no sé como es la sintaxis aún.
PD: así como está ahí, genera error.

Answer (score 5):

La forma correcta sería:

1. Agregar comillas simples (`'`) y escaparlas (`eg: \'`) para que el texto se imprima entre comillas.
2. Agregar algún texto antes de cerrar el tag `a` para poder hacer clic

#### Ejemplo:

```
$variable = "Hola mundo";

echo '<a onclick="funcionJS(\''.$variable.'\');">Click aquí</a>';
```

El resultado:

```
<a onclick="funcionJS('Hola mundo');">Click aquí</a>
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2de9971ac6592f1eaddf961e19f372e0a385ab19)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Si quisieras colocar un `string` sería:

```
$variable = "'Hola mundo'";
```

Al hacer el render queda así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero deberías corregir el echo a:

```
echo '<a onclick="funcionJS(' . $variable . ');"></a>';
```

O también:

```
echo '<a onclick="funcionJS('."'". $variable ."'".');"></a>';
```